# install Hashicorp vault on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to install vault on a google instance Redhat 7, and each time i run the script i tend to get a wired error for unsealing the vault, sometimes the unseal installation works sometimes does not, below are the error:

Installation code are [here](https://git.io/fjAxl) in git

when i try to unseal via comand vault operator init:

```
# vault operator init
Error initializing: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init
Code: 400. Errors:

* Vault is already initialized


   # echo $VAULT_ADDR
http://127.0.0.1:8200

 vault operator  unseal
Unseal Key (will be hidden): 
Error unsealing: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal
Code: 400. Errors:

* 'key' must be specified in request body as JSON, or 'reset' set to true
```

services are showing as:

```
 systemctl status vault.service
● vault.service - "HashiCorp Vault - A tool for managing secrets"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vault.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-08-27 20:28:59 UTC; 17min ago
     Docs: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/
 Main PID: 851 (vault)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vault.service
           └─851 /usr/bin/vault server -config=/etc/vault/config.hcl

Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: ==> Vault server configuration:
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Api Address: http://127.0.0.1:8200
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Cgo: disabled
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Cluster Address: https://127.0.0.1:8201
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Listener 1: tcp (addr: "0.0.0.0:8200", cluster address: "0.0.0.0:820...led")
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Log Level: info
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Storage: gcs (HA available)
Aug 27 20:29:02 instance-5 vault[851]: Version: Vault v1.2.2
Aug 27 20:29:03 instance-5 vault[851]: ==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full
```

based on the codes i should get auto unsealed

Answer (score 0):

From the command specified in the question, it looks like you are not specifying the key in the [unseal command](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/operator/unseal.html). To unseal vault you will have to present it with 3 unseal keys and run the command once for each of those 3 keys:

```
vault operator unseal key1
vault operator unseal key2
vault operator unseal key3
```

Five unseal keys are are printed out on the console when you [initialize vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/operator/init.html) for the first time, use any 3 out of those 5 keys to unseal the vault.